# Wildfly 8.1.0-3 deployment error with Expression language

Tags: spring, fedora, wildfly-8, undertow

I have problem with stactrace below during deployment of my simple application in war archive on wildfly 8.1.0-3.fc20 on fedora 20. Same application deployment on binary version of wildfly-8.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT succeeds. I would be grateful for help.

```
2014-10-05 12:36:07,435 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /WEB-INF/pages/main/Main.jsp: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec.jar:1.0.0.Beta1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:60) [log4j-web-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:229) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:172) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:159) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec.jar:1.0.0.Beta1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec.jar:1.0.0.Beta1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:67) [log4j-web-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl.<init>(ELContextImpl.java:72) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1188) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:844) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2433) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:510) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$IncludeDirective.accept(Node.java:656) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2433) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1768) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:211) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:359) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:326) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:604) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:309) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    ... 90 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.add(CompositeELResolver.java:117) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec.jar:1.0.0.Alpha1]
    at org.apache.jasper.el.ELResolverImpl.<clinit>(ELResolverImpl.java:51) [jastow.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    ... 116 more
```

Comment: Be sure you have all the **same** dependencies or jars on Linux too.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I asked the question incorrectly. I have solved my problem in a different way. I have configured ${wildfly_dir}/bin/init.d/wildfly-init-redhat.sh and ${wildfly_dir}/bin/init.d/wildfly.conf in my fedora. Then I have added init scripts on startup. After that I was able to boot wildfly on server startup without comparing dependencies between wildfly official version and native fedora package.